# The site of football club (CMS ready fo use)

Tags: cms, looking-for-a-script

Small football club wants to build your own site. Main sections: news, interviews, reports on matches, statistics, a list of players (photos, achievement), tournament standings, communication forum fans.

Maybe there are special engines (CMS) designed for this purpose? Scripts statistics and tournament standings of teams in the table should be integrated into the site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are few, but I didn't tested them:

- http://www.joomleague.net/ (a Joomla! plugin)
- http://www.liga-manager-online.de/homepage/

Answer (score 1):

I doubt there is a CMS that is custom purposed to your needs that will achieve everything you want. The good news is that there are a number of good CMS solutions out there that are flexible enough to accommodate for your needs, however they will require a good amount of custom development.

If you have no in-house developer, I would recommend searching for a good Drupal developer (Drupal is a highly powerful, highly customizable  CMS that could easily accommodate your needs) and getting a quote on the job.

Comment: "Drupal is a highly powerful, highly customizable CMS" That's true for most modern PHP CMS'es (incl. MODx, Joomla!, CMS Made Simple, TYPO3, …) See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_content_management_systems

Comment: Yes, however Drupal is a a true developers framework. Try writing something like this in Typo3.